# How do I get the user tag of users who reacted to a message embed?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm new to this and I'm having problems with the `Players: $join.get(joinReact).user` part.
It's only outputting `"Players: undefined".` I wanted it to store the ID so I can make the bot mention who's turn it is to answer.

*context: I'm trying to make a game where it kinda works like the tea game in mudae bot, where they have to react to the message to join the game.*

*this code is unfinished however and I've only done the joining part.*

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    const truthOrDare = {
        title: "Truth or Dare!",
        description: "Truth or dare commencing in 10 seconds! React with ✅ to join the game.",
        color: 16741492,
        footer: {
            "text": "You have 10 seconds to join."
        }

    };
    
    let msg = await message.channel.send({ embed: truthOrDare })
    await msg.react(joinReact);

    const join = await msg.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === joinReact,{time: 2000});

    if (`${join.get(joinReact) ? join.get(joinReact).count : 0}` >= 1) {
    message.channel.send(`The game is now starting. \nNumber of players: ${join.get(joinReact).count -1}\n`
    +`Players: ${join.get(joinReact).user }`);
    } else{
        message.channel.send("no players joined.")
    };
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "tod"
};
```

Comment: You have backticks in your `if` condition; that results in `"some String" >= 1` and is probably not what you want

Comment: The ``if`` statement is completely fine and working, it's the output of ``Players: $join.get(joinReact).user`` that I'm having problems with because instead of outputting the users, it's only outputting "undefined" the exact output is ``The game is now starting. 
Number of players: 1
Players: undefined``

Comment: It's a ternary expression, and you should wrap it in parens, not backticks and variable insertion curly braces. The point of these is to create strings, not change operator precedence. Anyway, regarding your actual issue: what is the result of `console.log(join.get(joinReact));`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EETsLw11
The result of ``console.log(join.get(joinReact));``

Comment: Right, I don't see `user:` anywhere in there? There's a `.users` property though, pointing to a `ReactionUserManager` object.

Comment: it gives me ``Players: [obect Object]`` as an output if I use ``.users``

Comment: Yes, that happens when you force JS to turn on Object into a String. Judging from the output, you need to iterate over `.users.cache` which is a `Collection` of users.